# First row only has one column in Tiled Gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, jetpack

I am using Jetpack tiled-gallery in wordpress. I don't want the first image to be full size. I can see from the markup that when it is generating the columns and rows for the images in the gallery that it only does one image for the first row.

I believe this behavior to reside here:

```
/jetpack/modules/tiled-gallery/tiled-gallery/tiled-gallery-square.php
```

I have tried commenting out some of the code and changed a few things, but have not found where it does the first row thing.

If anyone if familiar with this and can point me in the right direction or know a way to change this behavior, I would be greatful.

Additional info, my gallery is set to Square Tiles.
[website pertaining to the above](http://www.artbyclint.com)

Comment: please paste website link ?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj Hi, I updated the post to include the website link.

Comment: so you want to hide this image ? http://prntscr.com/f33qbb

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj No, I want all rows in the div that holds the images (`tiled-gallery type-square`) to have the same number of rows. The first row only has one column so the image width is the 1170px, but the subsequent rows have 3 columns so their width is roughly 1700px / 3. There is code in the jetpack modules that does this to the first row, but I can't find it.